# Why were there 100 bytes been written from buffer to file descriptor?

Tags: c, copy, buffer

I have the code  below, which copies "hello world" in buf[12] to the file foo.txt, and it did.

My question is:

There are only 12 characters (including the '\0' terminator) in buf[12], shouldn't the 'write' function just copy 12 characters to the file? Why were there 100 bytes been written to the file?  (I thought the 'write' function should only copies at MOST MAXLINE of bytes to the file.)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAXLINE 100 

int main() {
    char buf[12] = "hello world"; 
    int fd, writtenbytes;

    fd=open("foo.txt", O_RDWR, 0);

    if(fd == -1) {
        perror("Error opening file");
        exit(1);
    }

    if ((writtenbytes = write(fd, buf, MAXLINE)) < 0 ) {
        perror("writing");
    }

    printf("writtenbytes: %d\n", writtenbytes);
}
```

Output:

```
writtenbytes: 100
```

Comment: `write()` is not sensitive to C strings with null terminators. The code calls `write()` to output 100 bytes, so it does. If you want only to output the string, change `MAXLINE` to `strlen( buf )` as the argument to `write()`... PS: better to use `buf[]` over `buf[12]` and let the compiler measure the size. It's more reliable than any human counting characters.

Comment: Also note that the program as it's currently written has undefined behavior because `write` will access `buf` out of bounds.

Comment: @Fe2O3 Thank you for your comment! But even my code requests to write() MAXLINE(100) bytes to the file, but there were only 12 characters in the buf[12],  where were the rest of 88 bytes would write() copy from? ( @ Ted Lyngmo I expected some error to be reported by perror(), but it didn't.)

Comment: Where from? Memory is a contiguous block of bytes. Your code initialised 12 bytes beginning at an address (on the stack). `write()`, as written by @TedLyngmo, output (invoking UB) the contiguous 100 bytes beginning at that address. Lucky you! On another compiler or system, this may have caused a SEGFAULT (referencing memory that was not _claimed_ by the program.) C requires the programmer play by the rules. It doesn't babysit and watchout for these sorts of mistakes.

Comment: @Mory C doesn't work that way. You don't get clear errors when you have undefined behavior. You get a program that can act very strange. The extra bytes comes from just reading from whatever is in memory at those positions. If you are lucky, the program will crash. If you are unlucky, it will seem to work.

Comment: @Fe2O3  I asked ChatGPT, it gave me answer like this ---- The behavior you're observing is due to the way the write system call works in Unix-like operating systems. The write function does not know the exact size of the buffer you're passing to it. Instead, it relies on you to specify the number of bytes you want to write. In your code, you're passing MAXLINE (which is defined as 100) as the number of bytes to write, even though your buffer buf contains only 12 characters. (1-2)

Comment: @ Ted Lyngmo --- 
When you call write(fd, buf, MAXLINE), you're instructing the write function to write up to 100 bytes to the file descriptor fd. Since the buffer buf contains fewer bytes (12 characters plus a null terminator), the write function will write all 12 characters from buf and then pad the rest of the 100 bytes with whatever data happens to be in memory after buf. This is why you see 100 bytes being written to the file. (2-2)

Comment: ChatGPT doesn't know programming and it's therefore not a very good tutor. Regarding your comment:  _"When you call write(fd, buf, MAXLINE), you're instructing..."_ - **I** know that. That's what both Fe2O3 and I have said all along

Comment: "_I for one welcome our new computer overlords._" --Jennings after losing to Watson...

Comment: Thank you all for the comments! :)

Comment: Aside: `open()` and `write()` may not be the best way for a beginner to do file access. It's not part of the standard C library. Extra aside: always fun when the questioner argues with people.

Comment: @Ted Lyngmo Yes, you both were right, I appreciate  both of your help and time ! I recently started to use https://chat.openai.com/ to answer my questions and debug some code, it helped a lot, but sometimes it gave me misleading information.

Comment: @pmacfarlane ;)

Comment: @Mory Welcome to C. C has very few checks on arguments. If you direct code to `write()` more than it should, that is the programmers mistake. <I thought the 'write' function should only copies at MOST MAXLINE of bytes to the file> --> `write()` knows nothing about `MAXLINE` nor the size of the array it is reading. `write()` trusts that the sizes passed to it were good. The calling code lied to `write()` telling it to write 100 when at most 12 were available. Don't expect a C program to catch such mistakes. If you need the language to catch such mistakes, consider other languages.

Comment: @chux - Reinstate Monica Thank you for your comment!

Answer (score 2):

Short answer (to why your file is 100 bytes):

```c
#define MAXLINE 100
...
    if ((writtenbytes = write(fd, buf, MAXLINE)) < 0 ) {
        perror("writing");
    }
```

Your code says to write 100 bytes into the file.

You question though, is basically "why isn't there an error, because my array only has 12 bytes"?

Well, your code is flawed by trying to write 100 bytes from a 12 byte buffer. This is a bug in your code, and it will invoke Undefined Behaviour.

Sometimes Undefined Behaviour will generate a run-time error, such as a Segmentation Fault. Sometimes it will work as expected. Sometimes demons may be summoned out of your nose.

Your array `buf` is allocated on the stack, and there is probably plenty of free space there. So you won't get a SegFault. You'll just write a load of random crap into your file.

There's probably an existing answer to this effect, in which case, mark as dup.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!